# g++ can't find std headers(iostream,string etc.)

Tags: c++, c++11

My test code `test.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  cout<<"hello"<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

When i compile it via `g++ test.cpp`,I received the following error:

```
fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
```

My environment:

```
#g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/armv7hl-redhat-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/lto-wrapper
Target: armv7hl-redhat-linux-gnueabi
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --disable-build-with-cxx --disable-build-poststage1-with-cxx --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,go,lto --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-multilib --with-ppl --with-cloog --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-cpu=cortex-a8 --with-tune=cortex-a8 --with-arch=armv7-a --with-float=hard --with-fpu=vfpv3-d16 --with-abi=aapcs-linux --build=armv7hl-redhat-linux-gnueabi
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.2 20121109 (Red Hat 4.7.2-8) (GCC)
```

How do I solve this problem?Thanks for any help.

---

ok,that is the result of `g++ -v test.cpp`

```
Using built-in specs.

COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/armv7hl-redhat-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/lto-wrapper
Target: armv7hl-redhat-linux-gnueabi
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --disable-build-with-cxx --disable-build-poststage1-with-cxx --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,go,lto --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-multilib --with-ppl --with-cloog --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-cpu=cortex-a8 --with-tune=cortex-a8 --with-arch=armv7-a --with-float=hard --with-fpu=vfpv3-d16 --with-abi=aapcs-linux --build=armv7hl-redhat-linux-gnueabi
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.2 20121109 (Red Hat 4.7.2-8) (GCC) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-march=armv7-a' '-mtune=cortex-a8' '-mfloat-abi=hard' '-mfpu=vfpv3-d16' '-mabi=aapcs-linux' '-mtls-dialect=gnu'
 /usr/libexec/gcc/armv7hl-redhat-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/cc1plus -quiet -v -D_GNU_SOURCE test.cpp -quiet -dumpbase test.cpp -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mabi=aapcs-linux -mtls-dialect=gnu -auxbase test -version -o /tmp/cctwdZCf.s
GNU C++ (GCC) version 4.7.2 20121109 (Red Hat 4.7.2-8) (armv7hl-redhat-linux-gnueabi)
compiled by GNU C version 4.7.2 20121109 (Red Hat 4.7.2-8), GMP version 5.0.5, MPFR version 3.1.1, MPC version 0.9
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=85 --param ggc-min-heapsize=104357
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/armv7hl-redhat-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/armv7hl-redhat-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/armv7hl-redhat-linux-gnueabi"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/armv7hl-redhat-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/armv7hl-redhat-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/armv7hl-redhat-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/../../../../armv7hl-redhat-linux-gnueabi/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/armv7hl-redhat-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C++ (GCC) version 4.7.2 20121109 (Red Hat 4.7.2-8) (armv7hl-redhat-linux-gnueabi)
compiled by GNU C version 4.7.2 20121109 (Red Hat 4.7.2-8), GMP version 5.0.5, MPFR version 3.1.1, MPC version 0.9
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=85 --param ggc-min-heapsize=104357
Compiler executable checksum: cab4eacd06fac4cf3a5e1bf6dac7fc2e
test.cpp:1:20: fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Run `g++ -v test.cpp`. It should tell you what directories it's looking for includes.

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely due to the libstdc++-devel package not being installed.

Your compiler version indicates that you're running RHEL, CentOS, or Fedora. Execute the following command:

```
yum install libstdc++-devel
```

Comment: Why do you believe that the "package already installed"? Post the output of the "rpm -q libstdc++-devel" command. The package is libstdc++-devel, not libstdc++.

Comment: I executed the command,and it say:`Package libstdc++-devel-4.7.2-8.fc18.armv7hl already installed and latest version
Nothing to do`

Comment: Perhaps the installation was corrupted. rpm -q -l libstdc++-devel | grep iostream should show where iostream is installed by this package, pretty sure it should be /usr/include/c++/4.7.2, in your case. Verify that it exists. If you find that you have a corrupted installtion, use rpm -e libstdc++-devel to remove, and yum install to reinstall the package.

Comment: Try "locate iostream" and see whether it gives you something.

Comment: ` /usr/include/c++/4.7.2/iostream` is exist.I remove `libstdc++-devel`,but get an error:`Failed dependencies....needed by gcc-c++.....`,then i remove `gcc-c++` and `libstdc++-devel` and reinstall it.retest but problem persists.Thank you for your patience.

Comment: ` locate iostream` it output:`/home/wei/env3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/kernel/zmq/iostream.py
/home/wei/env3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/kernel/zmq/__pycache__/iostream.cpython-34.pyc
/usr/include/c++/4.7.2/iostream
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gfileiostream.h
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/giostream.h`

Comment: You say that /usr/include/c++/4.7.2 exists, but your error message: "ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/armv7hl-redhat-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2" -- this should map to /usr/include/c++/4.7.2. Perhaps some intermediate directories are missing. Does /usr/lib/gcc/armv7hl-redhat-linux-gnueabi exist?

Comment: `/usr/include/c++/4.7.2` is exist,`/usr/lib/gcc/armv7hl-redhat-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2` is exist too,but `/usr/lib/gcc/armv7hl-redhat-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2` does not exist.I tested by `ll`

Comment: I tested it again.`/usr/lib/gcc/armv7hl-redhat-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/../../../../` is exist,and `/usr/lib/gcc/armv7hl-redhat-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/../../../../bin` is exist too,but `/usr/lib/gcc/armv7hl-redhat-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/../../../../include` does not exist,and `/usr/include` is exist,I'm crazy

Comment: I `cd /usr/lib/gcc/armv7hl-redhat-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/../../../../include` it can skip to `/usr/include`...

Comment: Do you have any symbolic links in the /usr hierarchy, along this path? Is /usr/lib,  /usr/lib/gcc, or /usr/lib/gcc/armv7hl-redhat-linux-gnueabi a symbolic link? If you execute two separate statements: cd /usr/lib/gcc/armv7hl-redhat-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2 and cd ../../../../include -- what happens?

Comment: `/usr/lib` is symlink just as you say,it link to `../lib`,what shuld i do now?

Comment: There's your problem. How did that happen? If your Linux distribution installed it this way, file a bug with your Linux distribution. If you did this yourself, the rule is "you break it, you get to pick up the pieces". Creating a symlink /include => /usr/include will probably fix this particular error, but there could be other problems to follow, that will also need fixing.

Comment: All right.I know how to do it. Thank you very much for your help.